# Making a list of length X with each cell being a list of length Y

Tags: python, homework

My teacher gave us an assignment to write a function that gets as arguments an `x` and a `y`. It returns a list which is of length `x` and each cell is a list of length `y` so that the
`[i][j]` cell equals `(i+j)**2`.

```
# example input and output:
# input: x = 4 , y = 5
# output: [[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], [4, 9, 16, 25, 36], [9, 16, 25, 36, 49]]
```

I have written it down and I want to know if there is a more efficient way to write it.

```
def squared_sum_table(x, y):
    # Making a list of length x (last index is x-1)
    table = [None] * x
    # Making every index in table a list of length y
    for i in range(len(table)):
        table[i] = [None] * y
    # Assigning values to each cell
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            table[i][j] = (i+j)**2

    return table
```

Comment: If you really care about efficiency, this is what Numpy is for. I suspect, however, that that isn't what the instructor is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly beyond the scope of your current course, but if you care about efficiency, get rid of your loops and use vectorised Numpy expressions:

```
import numpy as np


def squared_sum_table(x: int, y: int) -> np.ndarray:
    i = np.arange(y)[:, np.newaxis]
    j = np.arange(x)
    return (i + j)**2


print(squared_sum_table(4, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  4  9]
 [ 1  4  9 16]
 [ 4  9 16 25]]
```

A note about dimensions. Your current code of

```
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            table[i][j] = (i+j)**2
```

seems to use [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) instead of row-major, since $$0 \le i \lt x$$ is your outer dimension. This is not advisable. The standard in most programming is row-major, which would use
$$0 \le i \lt y$$
$$0 \le j \lt x$$
with `i` outer and `j` inner. The suggested code above uses row-major, which is opposite to what you showed.

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to create a list, consider using a list comprehension**. Perhaps
your course has not covered this topic yet, but if you already understand
for-loops, a list comprehension will be fairly intuitive: it's basically a
mechanism to create a list using an inverted for-loop syntax. A similar syntax
can be used to create tuples or dicts.

```
def squared_sum_table(x, y):
    return [
        [(i + j) ** 2 for j in range(y)]  # Inner lists of length Y.
        for i in range(x)                 # The outer list of length X.
    ]
```

**Your current algorithm is convoluted**. You start with one structure (list of
`None` values); then you restructure (list of lists of size `y` holding
`None` values); then you fill in the values. That's a lot of hoop-jumping and does not
strike me as very intuitive. Here's how I might approach it. The process is straightforward in the
sense that we just keep appending as we go.

```
def squared_sum_table(x, y):
    # Start with an empty table.
    table = []
    for i in range(x):
        # Add an empty row.
        table.append([])
        # Add cells to that row.
        for j in range(y):
            cell = (i + j) ** 2
            table[-1].append(cell)
    return table
```

Answer (score 3):

Add items to simple lists indicating rows rather than table cells and use `append` function to add rows to the table:

```
def squared_sum_table(x,y):
  table=[]
  for i in range(x):
    row=[]
    for j in range(y):
      row.append((i+j)**2)
    table.append(row)
  return table
```

There is no need to use `None` or `table[i][j]`. Python has dynamic lists, so there is no need to initialize the table at the required size before use.

Comment: Good point regarding "Python lists being dynamic" added by @Mast.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is readable/understandable, which puts it ahead of the game. One modification (whether or not an improvement, be interested in feedback) is initializing the "table" within the last for-loop, like this:

```
def squared_sum_table(x, y):
    table = None
    # Init "table" and assign values to each cell
    for i in range(x):
        if table is None: table = [None] * x
        if table[i] is None: table[i] = [None] * y

        for j in range(y):
            table[i][j] = (i+j)**2

    return table
```